# How can i Disable Bootstrap DatePicker

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am trying to Disable the Bootstrap Date picker by adding the property disable="true", text-box is now disabled. when clicking on text-box the date picker still works how can i fix this issue.

**HTML**

```
<div class="input-group" id="DateDemo">
    <input type="text" id="txtPatientDOB" name="dd" data-format="MM/DD/YYYY" placeholder="DOB" class="form-control" disabled="disabled" /> <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-green" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
    </span>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
 $("#txtPatientDOB").attr("disabled", true);
```

Comment: hope your code is working fine https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/8081/

Comment: but after removing the attr disabled="true" then the date picker not works

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

Set date-disabled to "'true'" (all dates unclickable) and show-button-bar to "'false'" (buttons not visible).

```
<label>Date</label>
<p class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="dt"
       datepicker-popup="MM-dd-yyyy" is-open="opened" close-text="Close"
       show-weeks="true" show-button-bar="'false'" date-disabled="'true'" disabled />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-disabled" ng-click="open()">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
        </button>
    </span>
</p>
```

---

or Try setting Disabled property to true :

```
$("#Date").prop('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code to disable datepicker

**JS**

```
$(document).off('.datepicker.data-api');
```

Comment: $(document).off('#txtPatientDOB .datepicker .data-api'); its not working Nilesh

Comment: @kannanD.S So this is not what Nilesh wrote in his answer. I assume you want to try s.th. like `$('#txtPatientDOB').off('.datepicker.data-api');` or did I get it wrong ?

Comment: which version of bootstrap you are using?

Comment: @ Nilesh  Still its not Works iam using Bootstrap v3.3.1

Comment: @kannanD.S checkout this documentation: https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/bootstrap-datepicker/latest/bootstrap-datepicker.pdf...   3.1 Data API... page 11

Comment: @ Nilesh there is only one code in that PDF for disable the datepicker. But thats not working anjy other idea?

Comment: I will need to look into your working example. or a fiddle if you can provide?